# Expression Engine: Embed Template Variables not Working

Tags: templates, expressionengine

I am using the EE {embed} tag to bring in templates and as outlined in the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/embedding.html) I am setting variables in the tag to be used in the template.

All this is working fine for the first template I am embedding but any following {embed} tag does not seem to be able to set variables and all the variables within the template get outputted as plain text?

**Code:**

```
//main-template.html

{embed="includes/header" body_class="home" title="What Is"}
{embed="page/sub-nav" nav_title="what-is"}
{embed="includes/footer" }
```

The {title} for the header file outputs as "What Is" and the {nav_title} for the sub-nav file gets outputed as "{nav_title}"

Comment: Post the relevant code from your embedded templates?

Comment: Sorry I have been a bit code blind. I forgot to put the key word embed into to the variables. I was doing writing {nav_title} when it should have been {embed:nav_title}. But your comment made me look at it again so thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten to put the the "embed" keyword into the variable. So {nav_title} should have been {embed:nav_title}